# image hover zoom DELAY like google images

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, zooming, delay

There is code on js I've wrote from one video tutorial, but there is no delay before animation.
I've tried a lot of methods with delay() and setTimeout(), but didn't get needed result...

If someone could help me? please do it:)

I'll be very appreciate for this.

Here is code with posibility of edditing and running online: http://jsfiddle.net/S2svG/

And here is that js code:

```
$(function(){

    $.fn.popOut=function(user_opts){            
        return this.each(function(){

            var opts=$.extend({
                useId:"poppedOut",
                padding:20,
                border:0,
                speed:200
            },user_opts);

            $(this).mouseover(function(){
                // kill any instance of this already
                $("#"+opts.useId).remove();

                // make a copy of the hovered guy
                var $div=$(this).clone();

                // setup for prelim stuff
                $div.css({
                    "position":"absolute",
                    "border":opts.border,
                    "top":$(this).offset().top,
                    "left":$(this).offset().left,
                    "-moz-box-shadow":"0px 0px 12px black",
                    "-webkit-box-shadow":"0px 0px 12px black",
                    "z-index":"99"
                });

                // store all of the old props so it can be animate back
                $div.attr("id",opts.useId)
                    .attr("oldWidth",$(this).width())
                    .attr("oldHeight",$(this).height())
                    .attr("oldTop",$(this).offset().top)
                    .attr("oldLeft",$(this).offset().left)
                    .attr("oldPadding",$(this).css("padding"));

                // put this guy on the page
                $("body").prepend($div);

                // animate the div outward
                $div.animate({
                    "top":$(this).offset().top-Math.abs($(this).height()-opts.height),
                    "left":$(this).offset().left-opts.padding,
                    "height":opts.height,
                    "padding":opts.padding
                },opts.speed);

                // loop through each selector and animate it to its css object
                for(var eachSelector in opts.selectors){
                    var selectorObject=opts.selectors[eachSelector];
                    for(var jquerySelector in selectorObject){
                        var cssObject=selectorObject[jquerySelector];
                        $div.find(jquerySelector).animate(cssObject,opts.speed);
                    }
                }

                $div.mouseleave(function(){
                    $("#"+opts.useId).animate({
                        width:$(this).attr("oldWidth"),
                        height:$(this).attr("oldHeight"),
                        top:$(this).attr("oldTop"),
                        left:$(this).attr("oldLeft"),
                        padding:$(this).attr("oldPadding")
                    },0,function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    };
        $(".productBox").popOut({
            height:300,
            border:"1px solid #333",
            selectors:[{
                ".productDescription":{
                    height:150
                }
            }]
        });                    
});
```

Comment: What is the result you get with delay()? Is it doing the delay but not cancelling when the mouse moves or something?

Comment: He said, "but there is no delay before animation":-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/S2svG/48/

Cheers

Comment: Yes, looks like what I whant, except one small detail: when mouse out before zooming, the image anyway zoom. Here this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cngMj-pyr3U

Comment: I just edited my answer, new fiddle, added a line of code, that interrupts the animation -> $div.stop().animate();

Comment: If you'll be on Euro 2012 in Kiev (Ukraine) I'll treat you with dumplings and borscht and if you want our vodka)))

Answer (score 2):

If you want a delay between the mouseover event and animation you may want to have a look at [hoverIntent jQuery plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html):

> hoverIntent is a plug-in that attempts to determine the user's
>   intent... like a crystal ball, only with mouse movement! It works like
>   (and was derived from) jQuery's built-in hover. However, instead of
>   immediately calling the onMouseOver function, it waits until the
>   user's mouse slows down enough before making the call.

Having said that, you might want to have a look at [`jQuery.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/). [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/S2svG/53/).

Comment: The same problem as above: looks like what I whant, except one small detail: when mouse out before zooming, the image anyway zoom. Here this video: http://youtube.com/watch?v=cngMj-pyr3U

Comment: I wouldn't recommend an extra plugin, small but still 1,4K fro something simple you want

Comment: @Sylvio: you're right. I added an alternate method few minutes ago.

Comment: but how to fix problem with zooming when mouseout before 1 second??? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cngMj-pyr3U

Comment: @Vitali: I think it is as simple as adding a `.stop()` where necessary. Check the updated fiddle (revision 54) in a minute.